# How can I make my Chart.js dynamic with live data coming from MySQL?

Tags: jquery, json, xml, jakarta-ee, chart.js

How can I make my Chart.js dynamic with live data coming from MySQL? I am using Java EE. I am thinking of using JQuery, Ajax and XML/JSON. Is it a good idea or is there some better way?

Comment: When you say dynamic with live data, you mean in the background process or every time that the page is loaded?

Comment: I am thinking background process.